# What are `KEYCODE_11` and `KEYCODE_12` for?

Tags: android

Android 5.0 (API level 21) introduces two new keycode symbols to [`KeyEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html), namely [`KEYCODE_11`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_11) and [`KEYCODE_12`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_12), which ostensibly map to the "11" and "12" keys on the keyboard.  I have never seen a keyboard with an <kbd>11</kbd> or <kbd>12</kbd> key.

I had thought it might have something to do with watch faces, but then I noticed that there is no `KEYCODE_10`, making this all the more puzzling.

Comment: I believe that [Nigel Tufnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Tufnel) uses a keyboard that goes to 11. :-) My guess would have been function keys, but there already are `KEYCODE_F11` and `KEYCODE_F12`.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's kind of what I thought too, but also there's no `KEYCODE_F10` which is what makes it especially puzzling.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, they are used for the [HDMI-CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC) standard. Since some Android devices have an HDMI out, they can control TV's etc. with this standard. Also check out [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/96658f7%5E!/) for Android made last year.

Comment: Interesting, but where does CEC have keys 11 and 12, and why is there no 10?